# Action and Effects are not giving the Array of Objects

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am trying to fetch an array of objects that is into User.
I have created an Action and an Effect.

The User Model it is like this.

```
export interface User {
_id: string,
firstName: string,
lastName: string,
jobs?: UserJobs[];
}


 export interface UserJobs {
  jobId?: string;
  timestamp?: Date;
}
```

And into UserJobs there are 2 objects.
**[{"timestamp":"2022-10-05T21:21:24.917Z","jobId":"633df55439b18b2937a21ffd"},

{"timestamp":"2022-11-08T20:10:03.952Z","jobId":"636ab79b64211425baaf98e6"}]**

But still on the Redux Dev tools I am getting nothing.
I am getting this error on the console.

```
ERROR Error: Effect "JobsStateEffects.loadUserJob$" dispatched an invalid action: [{"timestamp":"2022-10-05T21:21:24.917Z","jobId":"633df55439b18b2937a21ffd"},{"timestamp":"2022-11-08T20:10:03.952Z","jobId":"636ab79b64211425baaf98e6"}]
```

And below i am getting like this.

```
ERROR TypeError: Actions must have a type property
```

Action.ts

```
export const userLoadJobs = createAction(
  '[UserJobs] userLoadJobs',
);
```

Effect.ts

```
  loadUserJob$ = createEffect(() => 
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(userLoadJobs),
      exhaustMap(action => 
      // Here If I use action it shows then nothing because my Service it is waiting for an ID      this.userService.getUserContactData(this.authService.userID).pipe(
          map(payload => payload)
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

This is the store select

```
export const jobsStateFeatureKey = 'jobState';

export interface AppState {
  jobState: InitialState;
}

export const selectJobsStateState = createFeatureSelector<InitialState>(
    jobsStateFeatureKey
);

export const selectUserJobs = createSelector(
      selectJobsStateState,
      (state: InitialState) => state.jobs
    )
```

Reducers.ts

```
export interface InitialState {
  job: Job;
  user: User,
  loading: boolean;
  error: unknown;
  jobs: UserJobs[];

}

export const initialState: InitialState = {
  job: new Job(),
  user: new User(),
  jobs: [],
  loading: false,
  error: undefined
};

const appReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(
    jobLoaded,
    userLoadJobs,
    updateJob,
    state => ({
      ...state,
      loading: true
    })
  ),
  
  on(JobsStateActions.jobLoaded, (state, action) => {
    const job = action.job;
    const loading = false;
    return {...state, job, loading};
  }),

    on(JobsStateActions.userLoadJobsSuccess, (state, { payload }) => ({
...state,
loading: false,
jobs: [...payload],
}
)),
```

}),

```
export function todoReducer(
  state: InitialState | undefined,
  action: Action
) {
  return appReducer(state, action);
}
```

This is the component

```
  userJobs$: Observable<UserJobs[]> = this.store.select(selectUserJobs);
   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch({ type: '[UserJobs] userLoadJobs' });
  }
```

Effect after discussion.

```
 loadUserJob$ = createEffect(() => 
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(userLoadJobs),
      exhaustMap(action => 
        this.userService.getUserContactData(this.authService.userID).pipe(
          map(payload => userLoadJobsSuccess(payload))
      // Here If I use action it shows then nothing because my Service it is waiting for an ID      this.userService.getUserContactData(this.authService.userID).pipe(
        )
      )
    )
    )
```

Action after comments.

```
export const userLoadJobs = createAction(
  '[UserJobs] userLoadJobs',
);

export const userLoadJobsSuccess = createAction(
  '[UserJobs] userLoadJobs Success',
   props<{payload: any}>()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

1- We get the data from the service into a `pipe` because it's `observable`

2- The `effect` dispatch the result (data) via `action`.

3- We create a `reducer` to get the data from the `action` to the `store` (do you use any reducer in the project? it's not clear in the question)

Here's an example how the effect reflex the result as an `action`:

```
  loadData$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(userLoadJobs),
    mergeMap(() => this.dataService.getAll()
      .pipe(
        map(data => ({ type: '[Data API] Data Loaded Success', payload: data })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      ))
    )
  );
```

Comment: I Use reducers in project I will add them, but in the effect into dataService.getAll as you suggested I need to give a paramId which is the authenticated User or someone else

Comment: That's fine. So just update the reducer with the new action.

The that I wrote was an example, so you can use it for inspiration.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the error you can see that the error is coming from the effects.

```
 loadUserJob$ = createEffect(() => 
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(userLoadJobs),
      exhaustMap(action => 
      // Here If I use action it shows then nothing because my Service it is waiting for an ID      this.userService.getUserContactData(this.authService.userID).pipe(
          map(payload => payload)
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

This is because the effect will dispatch the result to the store. In this case the `payload`. Because `payload` is not an NgRx action, it will throw the error.
As a fix, you should return an action instead of `map(payload => payload)`.
If the effect doesn't need to return an action, and just invoke a service make it a non-dispatching effect (which means that the effect does not dispatch to the store). https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/lifecycle#non-dispatching-effects

To dispatch an action, define the action and return it from the effect.

```
import {createAction, props} from '@ngrx/store';

export const userLoadJobsSuccess = createAction(
  '[UserJobs] userLoadJobs Success',
   props<{payload: any}>()
);

----

  loadUserJob$ = createEffect(() => 
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(userLoadJobs),
      exhaustMap(action => 
      // Here If I use action it shows then nothing because my Service it is waiting for an ID      this.userService.getUserContactData(this.authService.userID).pipe(
          map(payload => userLoadJobsSuccess(payload))
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: what should I do ?
Should I call dispatch false ?

Comment: I can't know that. That's up to you @TheCoderGuy, if you only want to call the server, then the answer is yes. If you also want to dispatch a success/failure action, then you should create an action for it.

Comment: I want to call the server and then all the time dispatch the data from store. Is that possible ?

Comment: I am still not getting the point.
I have the same code still no data

Comment: Check new code what I have done

Comment: I have been able to fix it but it is getting all the time data from effects and not from state/store